# Opening apps in same desktop

Tags: macos

I have 10.8.5.  I have a laptop with a larger monitor on an A/B switch.  I want to open AutoCAD on desktop 1 on on the main monitor.  I want to open Safari on desktop 1 on the laptop screen so I can take a class on Safari, and immediately do the work in AutoCAD.  I cannot get them to be on the same desktop.  How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want them both in full screen? You'll need Mavericks for that.

Answer (score 1):

On [10.8.5](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10688)

> After you connect the displays to your computer, you can choose
>   whether to use the displays as an [extended desktop or for video
>   mirroring.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5019) If you choose video mirroring, the displays each show the
>   same image. If you choose an extended desktop, the displays form one
>   large continuous desktop.
>
> If you are playing a DVD on a television connected to your computer,
>   click the Arrangement button in Displays preferences and move the menu
>   bar to the television. If you don’t see an Arrangement button, your
>   computer is only capable of mirroring (showing the same image on all
>   screens). For more information, see the manual that came with your
>   computer.

On [10.9.3 (Mavericks)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5891)

> With an external display connected to your Mac, you can work the way
>   you want. Each display has its own menu bar, and apps can run in full
>   screen mode on each display. Want to use your HDTV as another display?
>   You can easily do that with AirPlay and an Apple TV.
>
> Each display connected to your Mac can have its own windows and
>   full-screen apps. You can spread out your work however you like.